# Ubuntu, delete all files that start with '._'

Tags: ubuntu, rm

I want to delete all files that start with `._`, when I run this command:

```
me@me:/var/www/my/project$ sudo rm -Rvi ._*
rm: cannot remove `._*': No such file or directory
```

I'm pretty sure the `.` is causing problems, making it think I mean the current directory, what's the correct syntax to achieve this?

I know these files originated from my Mac, I need a way of nuking them :-)

Many thanks

Ben

Comment: Hmm, I cannot seem to be able to reproduce your problem. (`touch ._test`, `rm ._*` works fine.) Maybe there's some other attributes that make the difference?

Files beginning with a period aren't anything special, as it is the convention to 'hide' e.g. configuration files (~/.profile).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
find -name ._\* |xargs sudo rm -Rvi
```

or if your shell doesn't like that:

```
find |grep -e '^\._' | xargs sudo rm -Rvi
```

find without any arguments should just list *everything*.

Comment: Thanks! The first options worked fine when I did this: `find -name ._\* |xargs sudo rm -v` <-- left it with just verbose :-)

Comment: This won't work if filenames contains spaces or newlines. To support those, use find -print0 and xargs -0. 

According to a colleague, removing all ._* files messes up SVN directories. He uses `find . -type f -name "._*" -perm +w -delete`, because ._* files in SVN are not writable.

Comment: @Sjoerd, that is indeed more elegant.