# Unable to delete hidden files starting with "._", containing special characters

Tags: macos, nas, file-management, rm, escape-characters

The file name is `._03 Überlin.mp3`, and it lives in a folder on a Western Digital NAS external drive, being accessed on a Mac:

```
$ ls -al
total 128
drwxrwxr-x@ 1 kraftydevil  staff   264 Jul 23 03:58 .
drwxrwxr-x@ 1 kraftydevil  staff   296 Jul 24 05:30 ..
-rw-rw-rw-  1 kraftydevil  staff  4096 Aug 24  2013 ._03 Überlin.mp3
```

### Attempts

**Finder: Simple Delete**
[image]
Yields "The operation can't be completed because one or more required items can't be found. (Error code -43)"

**Finder: Delete Enclosing Folder**
[image]
Yields "The operation can't be completed because the item "album" is in use."

**Terminal: rm Attempts**

```
$ #escape the space
$ rm ._03\ Überlin.mp3 
rm: ._03 Überlin.mp3: No such file or directory

$ #escape the space and the 'Ü'
$ rm ._03\ \Überlin.mp3 
rm: ._03 Überlin.mp3: No such file or directory

$ #escape the space, the 'Ü', and the '_'
$ rm .\_03\ \Überlin.mp3 
rm: ._03 Überlin.mp3: No such file or directory

$ #use single quotes
$ rm '._03 Überlin.mp3'
rm: ._03 Überlin.mp3: No such file or directory

$ #use double quotes
$ rm "._03 Überlin.mp3"
rm: ._03 Überlin.mp3: No such file or directory

$ #use --
$ rm -v -- ._03\ Überlin.mp3 
rm: ._03 Überlin.mp3: No such file or directory
```

**Terminal: Delete With 'find'**

```
find . -type f -name "._*" -perm +w -delete
```

No output and the file persists

**Terminal: Delete By Inode Number Lookup**

```
$ ls -ali
total 128
94691 drwxrwxr-x@ 1 kraftydevil  staff   264 Jul 24 12:45 .
96821 drwxrwxr-x@ 1 kraftydevil  staff   296 Jul 24 12:33 ..
94756 -rw-rw-rw-  1 kraftydevil  staff  4096 Aug 24  2013 ._03 Überlin.mp3

$ find . -inum 94756 -delete
find: -delete: unlink(./._03 Überlin.mp3): No such file or directory
```

Comment: 1) What filesystem & where was it mounted when the -_ files were created? Best guess, not a Mac & that's a remaining resource fork/ACL attributes left over from another machine. 2) try sudo rm then just drag the file from finder to terminal - it should figure out any odd syntax requirement. 3) Run First Aid. Report back ;)

Comment: Or, at the worst, rename the folder, copy the contents *except for the one to delete* to a new folder with the original name, and delete the whole renamed folder.

Comment: Check ACLs on the file by running this command in the Terminal: `ls -le "._03 Überlin.mp3"`. Or try `dot_clean -m .` where the `.` is the path to the directory. And `.` means “this directory I am in right now.” More info can before [found here](http://www.phy.ohio.edu/~hadizade/blog_files/delete_._files_Mac).

Comment: @Tetsujin - 1) I believe it was a Mac. Even if it wasn't - there were other files starting with "._" in the directory that were successfully deleted using `rm -rf [parent folder]`, so it makes me think the issue is the special characters somehow 2) sudo yields the same  rm results 3) I'm unable to run First Aid. The drives don't show up in Disk Utility. I would expect them to show up under 'External' but only the hard drive shows up under 'Internal'. Running First Aid on the Internal hard drive yields normal results

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - unfortunately moving / renaming doesn't allow me to delete it

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - I had to add the a option to get any output. `ls -ale "._03 Überlin.mp3"` yielded `ls: ._03 Überlin.mp3: No such file or directory`. As for dot_clean,  `dot_clean -m .` run in the appropriate directory yields `unlink: No such file or directory
Merging /Volumes/Public/album/._03 Überlin.mp3 failed!`

Comment: Try Disk Utility again. Set to Show all devices [Cmd/2] I'm beginning to think it's an NTFS drive

Comment: What's the output of the `locale` command? What version of Mac OS are you using? [Possibly relevant Q + A's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399927/310780) -- on Unix & Linux SE, but about Mac, lol.

Comment: @Tetsujin - no luck with Cmd+2. Same list

Comment: Usually `find` does the trick: `touch ._03\ Überlin.mp3` followed by   
`find -type f -name .\*Ü\*3 -exec rm -v {} \; 2> /dev/null` gives me the expected result: `removed './._03 Überlin.mp3'`. It is necessary to repeat the spaces between the parameters and brackets.

Comment: does this help? https://superuser.com/questions/145447/ubuntu-delete-all-files-that-start-with

Comment: does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/988994/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-versions-of-files-starting-with-created-when-mov

Comment: I had this problem once on a Linux machine after extracting a few .lha archives. There were filenames containing international characters and the charset encoding was unsupported.  Files could not be accessed at all.  I ended up running `chown "${USER}:${USER}" ` on the parent directory to take ownership, then `chmod 000` on the same parent directory so the bogus chars couldn't be read. Then `rm -rf` successfully deleted that parent dir and all content.  Getting confused over illegal filenames is impossible when filenames aren't accessible. But you are still allowed to delete any dir you own.

Comment: Can you check if `fsck` reports any file system errors?

Answer (score 1):

Use the MacOS Finder ctrl-select (right click) -> Get Info on the file

You should then be able to edit the file name in the "Name & Extension" field.

I've just tested this with various combinations of special symbols and chars, and all seemed to be renamable back to some simpler charset with no difficulty.

If you *can't* then it's not the characters which are the issue, but likely the file system itself.

You say it's both a NAS [network attached] and an "external drive" - but I'd normally consider an external drive to be directly connected via USB or some other cable.

If it's attached via network, then some other process [on the NAS itself] may be holding the file open. Check whether the drive has a USB port for using as a local drive rather than network, as then you can do the following:

If it's USB, you should reboot into single user mode [hold Command+S on reboot] and try in the single user command prompt - where as a last resort you'll also be able to use fsck to check the drive, as per this explanation :https://www.maketecheasier.com/repair-mac-hard-disk-with-fsck/